# Plot ggplot line graph having 2 seperate columns value in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I have a dataset as follows-

```
    mo  Deposit Withdrawl
1   01  430013.5    363620
2   02  399733.5    364426
3   03  782495.0    897652
4   04  349144.7    395913
5   05  470808.5    410153
6   06  568985.0    720753
7   07  676970.2    355392
```

Now I want to plot a line graph which will show based on each mo (x-axis) , how is Deposit and Withdrawl working , precisely the graph will have mo as X axis and expecting 2 lines as Deposit and Withdrawl showing a line graph connecting to there points with different color in ggplot or qplot.

Tried

```
ggplot(data=month.dep,
       aes(x=mo, y=y, colour=Deposit)) +
  geom_line()
```

But above won't work as my objective is different and my colour type is no some binary value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `melt` your data into long format then plot it:

```
library(reshape2)   # For melt function

month.dep.m = melt(month.dep, id.var="mo")

ggplot(month.dep.m, aes(x=mo, y=value, colour=variable)) +
       geom_line()
```

In general, `ggplot2` prefers data in long format. In this case, `Deposit` and `Withdrawal` are two categories of currency values. So we use `melt` to put those two categories into a single column called `variable` that `ggplot` uses for the colour aesthetic, while the currency values likewise go into a new `value` column, each value going with its corresponding category in the `variable` column.